# Excel Macro to Shift Rows Up

Tags: vba, excel

I have an example Excel sheet that contains 6 rows as shown below (First column is meant to indicate row name not actual data).

```
A1  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10                                                                                                                                  
A2                                                                                                                                                                          
A3  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20                                                                                                                                  
A4  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30                                                                                                                                  
A5                                                                                                                                                                          
A6  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
```

What I'd like to do is write a macro to shift all of the rows containing data up to the top of the sheet.  I do not want to delete any rows.  The result shold be as indicated below.

```
A1  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
A2  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
A3  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
A4  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
A5                                      
A6
```

I have a simple macro to delete the blank rows which has a similar effect but I'd like to move the data instead.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()
On Error Resume Next
    Range("Sheet1!A1:Sheet1!A6").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Let me know what other information you need to help figure this out.

Comment: Just sort your data on one of the columns, the empty ones will go to the bottom.

Comment: @ScottCraner: This is just an example of a larger problem I'm working on.  This data will be on a locked, hidden sheet that the user will have to interaction with so manual sorting is not an option.

Comment: @DavidZemens: So far I've been able to write a function to delete all of the blank rows in the range but I'd like to look at automatically shifting the data up so no rows are lost.

Comment: @YowE3K: I've edited my post to make clear that the first column is meant to indicate row number not actual data.

Comment: Then use the macro recorder to record you manually sorting it then use that macro each time you want to sort it.

Comment: show your code...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly.

```
Sub SortData()
Sheets("Data").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a sorting method of removing the blank rows, you will need to do two sorts to keep their order(if this is important).

First, add a column with keys in it (eg 1,2,3,4,5,6), then sort by one of the other columns (putting the blank lines at the bottom).Then sort again by the column with the keys in after removing or deselecting the keys with blank rows, putting the items back in order with no blank rows.

If you want to copy and paste the data, you could loop through checking if row 1 is blank, and if so copy rows 2 to 7 into rows 1 to 6 (have row 7 blank), then repeat for rows 2 to 5 (for row 2, copy rows 3 to 7 etc).
No need to check row 6 - if rows 1 to 5 are full, then row 6 is correct either full or blank. If one of rows 1 to 5 were blank, row 6 is already blank from the first copy. Row 5 will also be blank by the time you get to it if you have two blanks in rows 1 to 4.